# Rails - Logging events with tags or types and getting an email alert - best practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, newrelic, airbrake, loggly

Wondering if someone could offer some best practice on logging techniques they use and maybe tagging certain events using airbrake or newrelic or loggly, or something of that nature?

For example, lets say I have events that should never hit my controller in theory, because they are protected on the front end - like a regular user being able to manage an admin. I prevent these controls from being outputted on the front end using ruby if statements. So if my controller gets hit with a request like this, then I know that either that code isn't working right, or someone is doing some hacking with the request being sent.

Either way I want to know. I just found myself writing:

```
#TODO: Log this. Either the front end is broken or the user is sending hacked requests
```

Wondering if anyone can offer some insight as to how they handle it, maybe with a third party logging tool, maybe with some sort of tag that I could set up email alerts with said tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morgan from Airbrake here. We don't have tagging for Airbrake Exceptions.

One way to solve this with our service is to send a custom error to Airbrake from your controller.
The error will trigger an Airbrake notification email and you will be notified.

For Example:

```
# find me in app/controllers/some_controller.rb

# custom error
class ControllerAccessError < StandardError
end

def action
  ...
  msg = 'front end is broken or the user is sending hacked request'
  e = ControllerAccessError.new(msg)
  Airbrake.notify_or_ignore(e)
end
```

Here is some more info on manually sending errors to airbrake with ruby:
https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/wiki/Using-Airbrake-with-plain-Ruby

Comment: Nice I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Jason from Loggly here. You can also setup a new Logger and then log anything you like. This uses pure Ruby code without any proprietary libraries. For example:

```
logger.warn("Regular user should not have access")
```

Even better, you can use JSON fields to make for easy reporting and filtering. I'm not a Ruby programmer, but I think it'd look something like this?

```
logger.warn({:username => username, :type => "Access Violation", :message => "Regular user should not have access"}.to_json);
```

In Loggly, you can setup alerts to be sent over email whenever you get a message matching this search

```
 json.type:"Access Violation"
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both, but stackoverflow only lets me accept one. This is great too. Thank you!